# Proper way for signal edge detection in Verilog

Tags: synchronization, verilog

I want to **detect a rising edge of a signal** from a flip-flop `AA` to `BB`

```
                    +----+
  A ----------------|    |----- OUT
        +----+      | BB |
  B ----|    |------|>   |
        | AA |      +----+
clk ----|>   |
        +----+
```

Verilog code:

```
    module edge_detect (
        input A,
        input B,
        input clk,
        output OUT
    );

        reg AA;
        reg BB;

        always @(posedge clk) begin
            AA <= B;
        end

        always @(posedge AA)begin
            BB <= A;
        end

        assign OUT = BB;
    endmodule
```

The output of `AA` is used as a clock to `BB` saying that `AA` has done its job and then `BB` can now continue its operation.

I rarely see this code. Is this a good practice?

If not, are there any other *proper way* to detect an edge of a signal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People tend to frown on using data as clocks for various reason.

Personally if I was writing this I'd go with:

```
module edge_detect (
    input A,
    input B,
    input clk,
    output OUT
);

    reg AA;
    reg BB;
    wire enA;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        BB <= B;
    end

    assign enA = !BB && B;

    always @(posedge clk)begin
       if (enA) begin
            AA <= A;
      end
    end

    assign OUT = AA;
endmodule

                                +----+
  A ----------------------------|D   |----- OUT
                     +---+      | AA |
      /--------------|   |      |    |
      | +----+       |AND|------|E   |
  B ----|    |------o|   |      |    |
        | BB |       +---+      |    |
clk ----|>   |          clk ----|>   |
        +----+                  +----+
```

The behaviour is a little different though.

Comment: `enA = not BB && B;` is equivalent to `enA = !BB && B;` and `if (enA) { ... }` is equivalent to `if (enA) begin ... end` in verilog. Anyway, can you state its advantage? Thank you for the quick answer. =)

Comment: Yes, I get VHDL/Verilog bleed through when writing into the editor.

Comment: The main advantage is that you're not having to deal with derived clocks, which can cause synthesis and layout programs headaches. Clocks tend be treated in a special way by various tools, so incorporating logic into your clock generation is discouraged most of the time.

Comment: These are sometimes called a 'one-shot' or Monostable Multivibrator.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna detect a rising or a falling edge in Verilog, simply pipeline or delay the signal by 1 clock pulse. In a digital environment, an edge can be thought of as a 0 to 1 transition or 1 to 0 transition.
So you can check if the signal made a transition to either state and then assert your output high only for that condition.

For example :

```
output out_flag; 
reg temp;    
reg temp_d;   
always@(posedge clk)
temp_d <= temp;    
always@(posedge clk)
begin
 if (temp && ~temp_d)
   out_flag<= 1'b1;
 else
   out_flag<= 1'b0;
end
```