# verilog mux on clock edge

Tags: verilog, multiplexing

How do I use clock edge as selector for a mux,
what I want to do:

```
input clk, in1, in2;
output out;
always@ (posedge clk) begin out<=in1; end
always@(negedge clk) begin out<=in2; end
```

however, this is not synthesisable because of multiple drivers in separate always blocks. Is there any work around?

Comment: Using clocks as data like this is normally a bad idea and for ASIC can lead to issues balancing the clock tree.

Comment: Is this using clock as data? It looks to me like capturing the value at certain time points. And is therefore a bit different than the other answer provided. I'm not really very experienced with verilog though so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @JohnB It's using the clock as an input to the cone of the data path, so I would say that it's the same thing as using the clock as data. Clocks should generally be for clocking only.

Comment: If you're trying to get a DDR signal you can do so on many FPGAs but you have to directly instance those primitives.

Comment: I had a similar problem before. You may detect the edge of a signal or a clock using an edge detecting circuit to avoid complaints from synthesizer. here is the link to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413661/proper-way-for-signal-edge-detection-in-verilog

Answer (score 6):

This should get you what you want.  Whether it is a good idea or not depends on what you are doing.

```
input clk, in1, in2;
output out;
assign out = clk ? in1 : in2;
```

Comment: From my experience, all the answers using double-edge flip-flops will not pass synthesiser. Only this answer provides a synthesisable solution. Using clock in combinational circuits is definitely bad but this one works.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, using clock as data is not common. A combinational mux be achieved using dwikle's answer, but if you really want to end up with flops (in that case ***out*** should be of type reg or logic, which is missing in your original code), then you can write:

```
always@(edge clk) 
begin
    unique case(clk)
        1'b0:    out <= in1;
        1'b1:    out <= in2;
    endcase
end
```

or equivalently you could use @(negedge clk  or posedge clk) instead of edge.
This may however, confuse your synthesis tool. Probably, the following is more straightforward:

```
always@(posedge clk) 
    out1 <= in1;
always@(negedge clk) 
    out2 <= in2;
assign out = clk ? out1 : out2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
module mux1_2(input clk, d0, d1,
              input sel,
              output reg y);

    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        case(sel)
            1'b0:    y <= d0;
            1'b1:    y <= d1;
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

However, you should follow the advice of the others. Multiplexers are very basic combinational devices, I don't see any situation where you would need to place a clock on it.