# Verilog: functionality like always & synthesizable

Tags: verilog

Is there any other functionality like `always` (that would only run if the sensitive signal changes and won't iterate as long as signal stays the same) which can be cascaded, separately or within the `always` , but is synthesizable in Verilog.

Comment: This would be very nice but I am not aware of any way to cascade `always` logic in Verilog. It would be obvious how to synthesize it but I don't think any synthesis tools are built to do it.

Comment: Its a very useful logic when we want some input with human (hardware switches) speed but wanna process them with clk cycles. There should be something.

Comment: something similar if you want to detect an edge of a signal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413661/proper-way-for-signal-edge-detection-in-verilog

Comment: @e19293001 Your provided code (Not Answer)  was good and simple. Thanx! btw!! you usrname equals to infinity ...  thats the point ??

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think there's a construct specifically like this in Verilog, there is an easy way to do this.  If you do an edge detect on the signal you want to be sensitive to, you can just "if" on that in your always block. Like such:

```
reg event_detected;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] sensitive_last;
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (sensitive_signal != sensitive_last) begin
        event_detected <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
        event_detected <= 1'b0;
    end
    sensitive_last <= sensitive_signal;
end

// Then, where you want to do things:
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (event_detected ) begin
        // Do things here
    end
end
```

The issue with doing things with nested "always" statements is that it isn't immediately obvious how much logic it would synthesize to.  Depending on the FPGA or ASIC architecture you would have a relatively large register and extra logic that would be instantiated implicitly, making things like waveform debugging and gate level synthesis difficult (not to mention timing analysis). In a world where every gate/LUT counts, that sort of implicitly defined logic could become a major issue.

Comment: If the `sensitive_signal` are already flopped in the `clk` clock domain, then `event_detected` should be combinational `always @* event_detected = (sensitive_signal != sensitive_last);` A smart synthesizer will treat it as such. It can save one flop, but you still need to flop all the bits to `sensitive_last` unless a encoding/compression can be applied. It is not that bad to debug/synthesis/timing-analysis if inputs are synchronized to the clock domain.

Comment: Good call on the combinatorial. W.R.T. Simulation and debug being more difficult, I just meant that in the case where `sensitive_last` is inferred instead of explicit (as the question seems to propose), there's no convenient way to peek at the register in a sim (since it has no identifier).

Answer (score 1):

The `assign` statement is the closest to `always` you you can get. `assign` can only be for continuous assignment. The left hand side assignment must be a `wire`; SystemVerilog also allows `logic`.

I prefer the `always` block over `assign`. I find simulations give better performance when signals that usually update at the same time are group together. I believe the optimizer in the synthesizer can does a better job with `always`, but this might depend on the synthesizer being used.

For synchronous logic you'll need an `always` block. There is no issue reading hardware switches within the always block. The fpga board may already de-bounce the input for you. If not, then send the input through a two phase pipe line before using it with your code. This helps with potential setup/hold problems.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  pre_sync_human_in <= human_in;
  sync_human_in <= pre_sync_human_in;
end
always @* begin
  //...
  case( sync_human_in )
  0 : // do this
  1 : // do that
  // ...
  endcase
  //...
end
always @(posedge clk) begin
  //...
  if ( sync_human_in==0 )  begin /* do this */ end
  else begin /* else do */ end
  //...
end
```

If you want to do a hand-shake having the state machine wait for a human to enter a multi-bit value, then add to states that wait for the input. One state that waits for not ready (stale bit from previous input), and the other waiting for ready :

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  case(state)
  // ...
  PRE_HUMAN_IN :
    begin
      // ...
     state <= WAIT_HUMAN__FOR_NOT_READY;
    end
  WAIT_HUMAN_FOR_NOT_READY :
    begin
      // ready bit is still high for the last input, wait for not ready
      if (sync_human_in[READ_BIT])
        state <= WAIT_HUMAN_FOR_NOT_READY; 
      else
        state <= WAIT_HUMAN_FOR_READY;
    end
  WAIT_HUMAN_FOR_READY :
    begin
      // ready bit is low, wait for it to go high before proceeding
      if (sync_human_in[READ_BIT])
        state <= WORK_WITH_HUMAN_INPUT; 
      else
        state <= WAIT_HUMAN_FOR_READY;
    end
  // ...
  endcase
end
```

Comment: **"It can only be for asynchronous combinational logic"** Is there any synchronous combinational logic? Or What? **"For synchronous procedural logic you'll need an `always` block"** What about asynchronous procedural logic? Innit confusing!!!

Comment: @tod, I cleaned up the wording. `assign` is continuous assignment (async). I never said you cannot have async procedural logic. I said I prefer grouping combinational logic into `always` blocks and even gave examples. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: When you add **"(async)"**, this makes it seem problematic. What don't you limit 'continuous assignment' to combinational/combinatorial logic cases? 
Whereas, asynchronous logic is a sub-class of sequential logic. So it should be like this: For sequential logic one will need procedural Verilog (i.e. `always` block).

Comment: **"`assign` can only be for continuous assignment"** or continuous assignment in Verilog does only use `assign`. You can mention the logic type also.

Comment: Your code is good! but sorry its not the answer!! I did the same thing with 3 case states and saw another much simpler code with 2 always@() blocks doing the same thing with 1 signal provided by @e19293001 thanx!