# FSM Verilog - 1 pushbutton for both start&stop

Tags: verilog, fsm

So I am pretty new to Verilog and I am trying to write a simple FSM.

Input `a` is a push button and by pushing it *starts* the machine. But every other next state, after initially pressing `a`, causes to go back to the start/initial state.

```
input clk, reset;
input a,b,c;

reg [1:0] state;
reg [1:0] nextstate;

parameter = START=2b'0,
            STATE1=2b'1,
            STATE2=2b'11;

always @(posedge clk)
 if(reset) state <= START;
 else state<=nextstate;

always @(state, a)
 case (state)
   START: begin if(a) nextstate<=STATE1; else nextstate<=START; end
   STATE1: begin if(a) nextstate<=START; else if(b) nextstate<=STATE2; else nextstate<=STATE1; end
   STATE2: begin if(a) nextstate<=START; else if(c) nextstate<=STATE1; else nextstate<=STATE2; end
 endcase
```

Keeping your finger on `a` now means my state is alternating between `STATE1` and `START` every positive edge of `clk`.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe the values should be specified using `2'b11` tick before the b not after.

Comment: Oh, yup. You are right. This was done only to showcase my problem, not the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to track the "edge" of the button, rather than the current state. For example:

```
reg aPressed, aPrev;
always @(posedge clk)
    aPrev<=a;

always@(*)
    if (a&&!aPrev) // a is high now, but was low last cycle
        aPressed = 1;
    else
        aPressed = 0;
```

In this code, `aPressed` is asserted only when `a` was low last cycle, and is high now (i.e. it was just pressed). If you replace `a` with `aPressed` in your next state logic, the user will be required to release `a` for a least one cycle before `aPressed` will trigger again.

```
always @(*)
    case (state)
        START: begin 
            if(aPressed) nextstate=STATE1; 
            else nextstate=START;
         end
        STATE1: begin 
            if(aPressed) nextstate=START; 
            else if(b) nextstate=STATE2;
            else nextstate=STATE1; 
        end
        STATE2: begin 
            if(aPressed) nextstate=START; 
            else if(c) nextstate=STATE1; 
            else nextstate=STATE2; 
        end
     endcase
```

*Side note: it's good practice to use* `always@(*)` *for combinational logic, rather than specifying the sensitivity list* (`always@(state,a)`)

Comment: Here is a similar topic on your answer: [Proper way for signal edge detection in Verilog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413661/proper-way-for-signal-edge-detection-in-verilog)